# rvm install crashes with bash error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I was installing Ruby 2.1.0 via ssh, and the session crashed before the install finished.  I logged back in and tried installing again with `rvm install 2.1.0`
and `rvm reinstall 2.1.0`, but both give me this error:

> -bash: 26%: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%")

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04, running rvm version 1.25.12, the latest stable version as of this writing.

FWIW, I checked in ~/.rvm/rubies and 2.1.0 is not listed.

Comment: `rvm remove 2.1.0` and try again

Comment: rvm remove 2.1.0 followed by rvm install 2.1.0 failed w/same error; but remove followed by reinstall worked!  Thanks!  Feel free to post your answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of this bug https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/2497 - please comment there with details of your system